# Does BCNF with a single-attribute key imply 4NF?

Tags: database

I would like to know if a relational schema is in BCNF with a single-attribute key, will it automatically be in 4NF?

I tried to derive it using table but how can I formally prove it without drawing table if the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember one of C J Date's books proving:

- BCNF and all keys simple ⟹ 5NF
- BCNF and any key simple ⟹ 4NF

The difficulty will be finding the right book.

A simple key is a key with a single attribute, just what you are asking about.

*[…time passeth…obscure sections of bookshelf are searched…]*

The book where I first came across it is:

- [Relational Database: Writings 1989-1991](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543036).  The theorems are in chapter 29, "Simple conditions for guaranteeing higher normal forms in relational databases".

It was also published by the ACM:

- [Simple conditions for guaranteeing higher normal forms in relational databases](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=132274&dl=ACM) by C J Date and R Fagin, ACM Transactions on Database Systems (TODS),
  Volume 17 Issue 3, Sept. 1992, Pages 465-476.

(You may need permission to get to that page.)

My memory was mildly inaccurate; the correct theorems are:

- 3NF and all keys simple ⟹ 5NF
- BCNF and any key simple ⟹ 4NF

The first result is slightly stronger than I originally stated because all relations in BCNF are also in 3NF but some relations in 3NF are not in BCNF.  The second was correctly stated.