# When to use the fifth normal form (5NF)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I am new at this form of normalization. I have worked before with the 4NF, but at the moment the 5NF it seems messy and I want to know if there is any rule that says when it is proper to apply this kind of structure or if I have to start thinking and working with it from now on.

PS: I have read about it and I kind of understand it; I just want to know if there are scenarios when it's better to use it or not, and if it so, when to.

Comment: At least 90% of the time in real life, you will find that if you've reached BCNF, you are also in 5NF.  Whenever possible, you should achieve 5NF; it will make your life easier (fewer update anomalies).

Comment: In amount of work, how much harder is to work with this 5NF?

Comment: IIRC, Date and Fagin proved that "BCNF plus all keys simple => 5NF" and "BCNF plus any key simple => 4NF".  A simple key is a one-column key.  For many tables, therefore, BCNF implies 5NF too.  When those rules don't take you to 5NF, I'd make absolutely sure of BCNF ("the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd") and mostly not worry too much.  If it seems cumbersome, maybe the design isn't right.  As to understanding 5NF fully — it's moderately tricky; I'm not sure I understand it fully.

Comment: I am just started to work with it, at the moment looks complicated but I hope to master it soon. Thanks for your answers. @JonathanLeffler Leffler

Comment: See also [Does BCNF with a single-attribute key imply 4NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672825/does-bcnf-with-a-single-attribute-key-imply-4nf) and maybe [Database Design and Relational Theory: Normal Forms and All That Jazz](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uds1DyR0U8IC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113)

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a subjective topic. But my subjective opinion is that the 5NF is really more of a theoretical concept than a practical one. I've been developing databases for 20+ years and have never gone to that extent, or ever wanted to.

In practice it means that your database is already in 4NF and cannot be further decomposed without loss of data.

Comment: Thanks @Randy I wish I were part of the team that stated that we should work with the 5NF, but at the moment I have to deal with it. Further now I know that I have to avoid at possible this 5NF.

Answer (score 0):

> When to use the fifth normal form (5NF)?

Only during interviews, not in real. That's extreme. Even during interview you are asked to explain database normalization, you are really not expected to go till 5th one. First 3 and you will be selected. :)

Comment: It seems an useful theoretical knowledge. Thanks for answer.

Comment: True. Because like others here, I too haven't thought of or seen anybody doing it. You have just started, eventually you will realize the same, that it is only good in theory. :) I would rather focus on mastering first 3 forms.

Comment: Go for BCNF, which is strictly stronger than 3NF.

Comment: I've gone to 5th many times for applications. I've been database for 30+ years, and applications that have millions of records with relationships lend themselves to 5th